# Regex through a string with Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I currently have the below contained within a HTML response I'm processing in BeautifulSoup4:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var n='eut';
var u='user'+'/8/'+'41140658'+n.charAt(2)+n.charAt(0)+n.charAt(1);
document.getElementById('big_pic').src='http://b2.eu.album.com/'+u.charAt(0)+'/'+u+'.jpg';
</script>
```

What I am wanting to achieve is to be able to extract the letter that succeeds *('big_pic').src='http://*, in this case, the letter 'b'

I've tried the below but I just don't know how to return the letter AFTER the string:-

```
my_string = str(re.findall(r'('big_pic').src='http://', the_string))
```

How can I return the letter that comes AFTER 'http://' in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive look-behind:

```
>>> re.search(r"(?<=\('big_pic'\)\.src='http://).", the_string).group(0)
'b'
```

`findall` will return an array of all matches:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\('big_pic'\)\.src='http://(.)", the_string)
['b']
```

So when using `findall` you should also take care of taking the match you want.

Comment: Thanks, it's even simpler

Answer (score 0):

There're a couple errors in your implementation.

First, if you know the exact string you're looking for why are you using regex? You can simple search for the string.
With the index that starts your string and the length of the string you are looking for you can simply retrieve the char in the position you want.

Second, you are using single quotes for both start your string and for the quote inside the string, it shouldn't even run without an error (except if the error was only when you posted it here)

Doing those changes your code would look like this:

```
idx = the_string.find(r"('big_pic').src='http://")
if idx > -1:
        my_string = the_string[idx+24:idx+25]
```